# Magento 2.3.0 Admin grid using UI component sticky CSS is not working

Tags: admin, grid, css, uicomponent, magento2.3.0

I have created a grid using UI component. in this grid, I display only grid I don't need to display button `<buttons></buttons>`. gird is working perfectly when I scroll down in grid page sticky CSS is not working and grid layout is brek.

When I add a button using `<buttons></buttons>` and scroll down element sticky grid is working fine but if I remove button `<buttons></buttons>` (I remove button because I don't want) and scroll down sticky grid is not working.

**What actual result :**

[image]

**What Expected result :**

[image]

It is default Magento bug [I Report an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22614)

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Have you check consol or log file?

Comment: I have checked everything, you can try with any admin grid using Ui component just remove Button displaying above grid  and check sticky CSS is not working.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to solve this

1st way

Remove the sticky tool from the uicomponent ie.Remove these lines from the ui component

```
<settings>
<sticky>true</sticky>
</settings>
```

2nd way

Override the  app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/grid/toolbar.js in app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Ui/view/base/web/js/grid/toolbar.js and add the if condition as given below

```
    show: function () {
    this.visible = true;
    //Add this if condition in the override js file 
    //Check admin grid button has added not 
    if ($('.page-main-actions').length === 0) {
        this.$sticky.style.top = 0;
    }
   //End of the condition
    this.$sticky.style.display = '';
    this.$toolbar.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Hope it Solves .Happy Coding :)